# Show that the following is only continuous at x=0

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

[image]

What is this question asking?
How does rational and irrational affect it? What are the absolute values used for in this solution?
Why is the series irrational when $c\ne0$ for any nonzero rational number but then the series is made to be all irrational values?

What is this question?

Comment: Well, can you see that the function is discontinuous at $x=1$?  What about $x=\pi$?   Can you see what is special about $x=0$?  The absolute value is, of course, the usual absolute value.

Comment: @lulu
No I cannot. Does it not fit the criteria for continuity at a point? 
"i.)f(a) is defined
 ii.)limx→af(x) exists
 iii.)limx→a+f(x)=limx→a−f(x)=f(a)"

Comment: work out the case $x=1$ say. of course $f(1)=1$.  Were it continuous there, then $f(1+\epsilon)$ would have to be nearly $1$, for small $\epsilon$ of course.  Indeed, $f(1+10^{-10})$ is very near $1$.  But what about $f\left(1+10^{-10}\pi\right)$  is that very near $1$?

Comment: @lulu I assume it would be considering how small the denominator is.

Comment: Well, what does the definition say?  It's clear that $1+10^{-10}\pi$ is irrational (is it not?) so then $f(1+10^{-10}\pi)=-(1+10^{-10}\pi)$ which is near $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: @lulu Could I not fit many rational ϵ in a row before getting to an irrational ϵ therefore making it a continuous stretch? Coming from both the left and the right if we do this it fits criteria iii.)?

Comment: That does not make sense.  The definition of continuity requires that *every* $x$ near enough to a fixed $x_0$ must be such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ is small.  Phrased (slightly) differently, if $\lim x_n=x_0$ then $\lim f(x_n)=f(x_0)$.  But in our case, with $x_0=1$, we define $x_n=1+10^{-n}\pi$ and see that $\lim x_n=-1\neq f(1)$.

Comment: It's a little more work to see what happens if $x_0$ is irrational.  With $x_0=\pi$, say, we  define $x_1=3.1$, $x_2=3.14$, $x_3=3.141$ and so on.  Then $\lim x_n=\pi$ and $\lim f(x_n)=\pi\neq f(\pi)$.

Comment: @lulu so because you can place an irrational ϵ anywhere in there it would render it noncontinous by the piecewise constraints

Comment: Well, that's a bit vague.  But, sure.  Now go through the argument with $x_0=0$.  That's very different from $x_0=1$.   Very different from any other rational for that matter.  Why?

Comment: @lulu "The definition of continuity requires that every x near enough to a fixed x0 must be such that |f(x)−f(x0)| is small." So if there is a long string of adjacent rational values coming up to 1, x->1, why doesn't that fit the definition provided?

Comment: You aren't following my comments.  Once again:  the key word in the passage you quoted is "*every*".  The fact that you can find "some" $x_n$ near $x_0$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|$ is nice but not good enough.  You need to work with *all* the $x_n$ near $x_0$.

Comment: As a related exercise:  consider the function $g(x)$ which is $1$ if $x$ is rational, and $0$ if $x$ is irrational.  Show that $g$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: So for it to be continuous we essentially need to account for every number from -infinity and +infinity and if there is a single break on either side then it is not continuous at the point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120099/discussion-between-user312484-and-lulu).

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$ f $ is continuous at $ 0 $ because

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\;|f(x)|=|x|$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0=f(0)$$

Let $ a\ne 0$ rational.
Take, for $ n $ great enough,

$$a_n=a+\frac{\pi}{n}\notin \Bbb Q$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}(-a_n)=-a\ne f(a)$$

Let $ b $ be an irrational number.
Take
$$b_n=\frac{\lfloor 10^nb\rfloor}{10^n}\in \Bbb Q$$
then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(b_n)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}b_n=b\ne f(b)$$

Comment: Nice proof (+1)

Comment: @Angelo Thank you. {}{}{}{}{}